# Actual column names instead of * in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following query (sample)

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_1 1 INNER JOIN
Table_2 2 ON 1.C1 = 2.C1 INNER JOIN
Table_3 3 ON 2.C2 = 3.C2 INNER JOIN
Table_4 4 ON 3.C3 = 4.C3
```

The output is of 10+ columns.

When I hover over * (after "SELECT") I get a tooltip with all different column names from those 4 tables.

Is there a way to easily switch from * to those column names instead of typing each one of them after SELECT?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you guys for your fast input. dragging the columns folder feels like a magic trick to me right now. This way, I don't make any spelling mistakes while manually typing column names...pretty cool tip. Also, doing this in query designer also seems to be a good alternative. Thanks guy!

Comment: Dont forget to delete the redundant column  after you do this, at mumimum the join fileds are repeats of each other. And get rid of any other fileds you are not specifically using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you're working in Management Studio. If so, go to the Object Explorer and open up your Table. Left click on the Columns folder and drag it to your query window. All the columns for that table will be listed.

Answer (score 3):

From the Object Explorer of SQL Server Management Studio, you can expand a table (so you see the Columns, Keys, Indexes, etc folder breakdown).  Dragging the `Columns` folder to your query window will give you a comma separated list of the column names.

Please note: If there are duplicate column names among your four tables, you will have to properly quantify these columns properly.

Answer (score 3):

I see your query references 4 tables.

To avoid having to locate and expand the 4 different objects in object explorer you can also select the query text in management studio, right click and choose "Design Query in Editor" then copy the column names out of the expanded list

Copying the column names rather than simply pressing OK avoids the designer messing up your formatting and possibly your query as well.

Expanding wildcards is part of the functionality of [Redgate SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) if you have this need frequently.

Answer (score 0):

If you use DataGrip for writing SQL, you can press Alt+Enter -> Expand column list [image]